# Append a list to a sequence of lists

Tags: clojure

I have a sequence of lists:

```
(def s '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
```

And I want to append another list to the tail of this sequence, i.e.

```
(concat-list s '(7 8))
=> '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (7 8))
```

Various approaches that (obviously) don't work:

```
(cons '((1 2)) '(3 4))
=> (((1 2)) 3 4)

(conj '(3 4) '((1 2)))
=> (((1 2)) 3 4)

(concat '((1 2)) '(3 4))
=> ((1 2) 3 4)

;; close, but wrong order...
(conj '((1 2)) '(3 4))
=> ((3 4) (1 2))

;; Note: vectors work - do I really have to convert entire 
;; structure from lists to vectors and back again?
(conj [[1 2]] [3 4])
=> [[1 2] [3 4]]
```

What are some possible implementations of `concat-list`, or does there exist library function that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better solution, but here's one way:

```
user=> s
((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))
user=> s2
(7 8)
user=> (concat s (cons s2 '()))
((1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (7 8))
```

Comment: As `(cons s2 '())` equals `(list s2)`, the solution is better written as  `(concat s (list s2))`

Comment: @TerjeD., thanks, that's better. I haven't really written any code in Clojure yet, just played with the REPL for this. :)

Comment: @TerjeD. Concat only  works with lists ```(concat '(1) '(2)) => (1 2)``` 

List gives 
```(list 1 '(2)) => (1 (2))``` . and 

Cons gives  
```(cons 1 '(2))  => (1 2)``` thus ```cons``` is a better choice to append individual elements into a list. Thus it works with both lists and atoms.

Answer (score 4):

If you find this collection is usually growing to the right, then you should start it off as a vector and keep it that way.That will be the most efficient and convenient.

However, if this collection mostly grows to the left and only rarely to the right, concat is probably your best option:

```
(concat '((1 2)) ['(3 4)])
```

Note that concat returns a lazy sequence, not a persistent list.

If the collection is large and grows frequently on both ends, you may want a more advanced collection type like a finger tree or a flexvec.